# Почему авторизация emqx клиента mqtt не работает?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mqtt

Я использую emqx mqtt broker для создания сервера.
У меня есть docker compose. В котором есть postgresql и emqx.
При запуске контейнера все нормально, emqx запускается спокойно, но в дальнейшем клиент никак не может авторизоваться, учитывая, что я ввожу точно правильные данные авторизации. Итак, я думаю, что в настройке контейнера emqx допущена ошибка.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:14.8-alpine3.18
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "max_connections=50"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_buffers=1GB"
      - "-c"
      - "effective_cache_size=4GB"
      - "-c"
      - "work_mem=16MB"
      - "-c"
      - "maintenance_work_mem=512MB"
      - "-c"
      - "random_page_cost=1.1"
      - "-c"
      - "temp_file_limit=10GB"
      - "-c"
      - "log_min_duration_statement=200ms"
      - "-c"
      - "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=10s"
      - "-c"
      - "lock_timeout=1s"
      - "-c"
      - "statement_timeout=60s"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.max=10000"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.track=all"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../2. Init Database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mosquitto/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.2
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PG_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PG_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - postgres

  emqx:
    container_name: emqx_container
    image: emqx/emqx:4.3.5
    environment:
      EMQX_NAME: emqx
      EMQX_HOST: "localhost"
      EMQX_NODE__DIST_LISTEN_MAX: 6379
      EMQX_LOAD__DIST_MAX: 64
      EMQX_CLUSTER__ACCEPT_SYS_HEARTBEAT: "true"
      EMQX_CLUSTER__NODE__NAME: "emqx@127.0.0.1"
      EMQX_LISTENER__TCP__EXTERNAL: 1883
      EMQX_LISTENER__WS__EXTERNAL: 8083
      EMQX_CLUSTER__DISCOVERY__STATIC__SEEDS: "emqx@127.0.0.1"
      EMQX_PLUGINS: "emqx_auth_pgsql"
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__SERVER: "postgresql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${DATABASE_NAME}"
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__SUPERUSER: ${MQTT_USER}
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__SUPERUSER_PASSWORD: ${MQTT_PASSWORD}
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__STARTUP_RETRIES: 3
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__POOL__SIZE: 8
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__POOL__MAX_OVERFLOW: 10
      EMQX_AUTH__PGSQL__QUERY__USER: "SELECT secret FROM 'Wardrobe' WHERE mac = '$1'"
      EMQX_LOG__LEVEL: debug
      EMQX_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: "false"
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "8083:8083"  # Для поддержки MQTT-over-Websocket
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
    networks:
      - mqtt-net

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  data:
    name: "mqtt-broker-data"

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

  mqtt-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.10.0/24

  postgres-data:
```

Это мой докер контейнер
Ниже будет пример запроса на подключение

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.username_pw_set(username="11:11:11:11:11:11", password="1")
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=1883, keepalive=60)
client.subscribe("test")
msg = json.dumps({"from": 0,"name": "Alex", "age": 123})
client.publish(topic="test", payload=msg, qos=0)
client.loop_start()
```

emqx ответ:

```
2024-01-29 23:50:55 2024-01-29T20:50:55.938874+00:00 [info] MzE0ODA1MDI0MjM3NTcwOTY2MzAwNjUyNTk4MTY4MTI1NDE@172.100.10.1:48590 file: emqx_connection.erl, line: 520, mfa: {emqx_connection,terminate,2}, msg: terminate, pid: <0.2130.0>, reason: {shutdown,not_authorized}
2024-01-29 23:50:56 2024-01-29T20:50:56.213804+00:00 [debug] 172.100.10.1:48592 [MQTT] RECV <<16,34,0,4,77,81,84,84,4,194,0,60,0,0,0,17,49,49,58,...>>
2024-01-29 23:50:56 2024-01-29T20:50:56.213921+00:00 [debug] 172.100.10.1:48592 [MQTT] RECV CONNECT(Q0, R0, D0, ClientId=, ProtoName=MQTT, ProtoVsn=4, CleanStart=true, KeepAlive=60, Username=11:11:11:11:11:11, Password=******)
2024-01-29 23:50:56 2024-01-29T20:50:56.214042+00:00 [warning] MzE0ODA1MDI0Mjg4MzY4ODcyMjYxMDcxMDEzMDI2ODU2OTG@172.100.10.1:48592 [Channel] Client MzE0ODA1MDI0Mjg4MzY4ODcyMjYxMDcxMDEzMDI2ODU2OTG (Username: '11:11:11:11:11:11') login failed for not_authorized
2024-01-29 23:50:56 2024-01-29T20:50:56.214104+00:00 [debug] MzE0ODA1MDI0Mjg4MzY4ODcyMjYxMDcxMDEzMDI2ODU2OTG@172.100.10.1:48592 [MQTT] SEND CONNACK(Q0, R0, D0, AckFlags=0, ReasonCode=5)
2024-01-29 23:50:56 2024-01-29T20:50:56.214204+00:00 [info] MzE0ODA1MDI0Mjg4MzY4ODcyMjYxMDcxMDEzMDI2ODU2OTG@172.100.10.1:48592 file: emqx_connection.erl, line: 520, mfa: {emqx_connection,terminate,2}, msg: terminate, pid: <0.2131.0>, reason: {shutdown,not_authorized}
```

postgres.Wardrobe:
доказательство того, что у меня существует такой пользователь с таким secret

[db data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1juF.png)

У меня есть два варианта относительно того, в чем заключается эта проблема:
1: Контейнер настроен неправильно
2: Что касается первого, у меня есть неправильно настроенная ссылка на попытку авторизации

Help me